# Time for tea: cake division by lines

Tags: geometry

This 'cake division by lines' problem was used as an example in one of the lectures I attended at business school.

I've searched and it doesn't seem to be on the site yet, so here it is:

> You have a cake and a knife.
>
> You may cut the cake, with the knife, three times, in any direction.
>
> You may *not* break the cake into pieces with your fingers (it's unhygienic) or in any other way apart from using the knife.
>
> Each cut must be in a straight line.
>
> What is the maximum number of pieces into which you can cut the cake?

The pieces don't all have to be the same size.

Comment: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2827/cutting-a-cake-into-8-pieces

Comment: @d'alar'cop: not the same puzzle, although they do both involve cake. 8 is not the correct answer to this one.

Comment: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/3801/slicing-a-donut-3-ways-whats-the-most-number-of-pieces

Comment: This is a vague question. What shape is the cake? If we don't know, we can't answer. It would be one thing if the answer relied on the idea that it doesn't matter what the shape was, but it does matter.

Comment: @EnvisionAndDevelop: Yes. The question tests whether you will make the assumption that the cake is a standard 'cake shape' such as round or rectangular. That's the puzzle.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> It depends on shape of the cake. for example with this one you can make too many pieces with only one cut:
>
>  [image]
>
>  but suppose shape of cake is convex like a Cube or Cylinder. The answer should be 8 pieces this way:
>  
>  [image]

Comment: aw, so quick! Correct answer is your first sentence.

Comment: spoiler: https://bakersedge.com/products/edge-brownie-pan